# Swapping Between Forms VBA + Centering on Duel Screens

Tags: forms, vba

I am trying to have my `Main Menu` and Subsequent forms operate together properly. what I'm currently having happen is on the second click of `Employee_Form` button the form loads back up but then Jumps to the end of `QueryClose Sub` and closes the form for some reason!

I Have the following code :

This activates when i click the relevant button to load the employee_Form.

```
Private Sub EmpChecker_Click()
    Main.Hide
    Employee_Form.Show False

End Sub
```

This then activates when i close the Employee form.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose()
        Employee_Form.Hide
        Main.Show
End Sub
```

As i say when i click `EmpChecker` Button again the form will show up in debug but then jump to the end of the above code and close the form.

Any ideas? I'm a little mythed as to why this happens.#

My Next Question is about centering the forms. We use 4 screens at work attached to one Computer I Have tried all 4 options in properties of each form but each one i use the forms seem to center in the Second Screen. its rather annoying! is there anyway to just get them to load into the default screen that Excel is in!?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `False` argument

```
Private Sub EmpChecker_Click()
    Main.Hide
    Employee_Form.Show
End Sub
```

To center your `UserForm`, there's no automatic way to do, you need to do using some code.

```
With UserForm1
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show
End With
```

To locate your user form in the right screen, you can ask for the current window position.

Hope this helps.